# Unexpected c# interface implementation compiler error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, interface, implementation

I just came across this weird behavior today:

```
interface IFooBar
{
    void Foo();
    void Bar();
}

class FooBar : IFooBar
{
    void IFooBar.Foo()
    {
    }

    void IFooBar.Bar()
    {
        this.Foo();
    }
}
```

The line this.Foo(); raises the compiler error

> 'MyProject.FooBar' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Foo' and no extension
>   method 'Foo' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'MyProject.FooBar'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

If I choose public methods instead of the interface.method declaration style, the code compiles:

```
class FooBarOk : IFooBar
{
    public void Foo()
    {
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        this.Foo();
    }
}
```

I'd like to understand why this error is raised, and how it can be worked around using the interface.method notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around it, you can write:

```
((IFooBar)this).Foo();
```

Take a look at the [Explicit Interface Implementation Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(VS.71).aspx) for answer why `this.Foo()` doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the link and the magic sentence: "When a member is explicitly implemented, it cannot be accessed through a class instance, but only through an instance of the interface."

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the interface syntax in code?

```
((IFooBar)this).Foo ();
```

I expect it's because the implementation is effectively hidden, ensuring that you must cast it to an `IFooBar` in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is called explicit interface implementation.  It lets you implement an interface without exposing those methods publicly.  For example you could implement IDisposable but provide a public Close() method which may make more sense to the users of your api.  Internally the IDisposable.Dispose() method would call your Close method.

```
interface IFooBar
{
    void Foo();
    void Bar();
}

class FooBar : IFooBar
{
    void IFooBar.Foo()
    {
    }

    void IFooBar.Bar()
    {
        ((IFooBar)this).Foo();
    }
}
```

is a way for you to call the Foo method